# Rails 4 - mailer - how to pass arguments to a mailer method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, actionmailer

I'm trying to figure out how to setup a mailer class in my Rails 4 app.

I have made a mailer called admin_notes. I want to use it to send emails to the internal team when certain actions are taken across the site.

In my mailer/admin_note.rb, I have:

```
class AdminNote < ApplicationMailer

    def unknown_organisation(organisation_request, user_full_name, name)

     @organisation_request = 
     @user_full_name = 
     @organisation_request.name = 

        # @greeting = "Hi"
    mail( to: "test@testerongmail.com",from: "test@testerongmail.com", subject: "A new organisation")

  end
end
```

I have an organisation_requests model. It has:

```
class OrganisationRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  delegate :user_full_name, to: :profile, prefix: false, allow_nil: true
```

The organisation request table has an attribute called :name in it.

When a new organisation request is created, I want to send an admin note to the internal team, alerting someone to start a process.

I'm struggling to figure out how I define the three variables in the mailer method.

I plan to add the send email call to the create action in the organisation requests controller.

How can I set these variables?

Form to create an organisation request is:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@organisation_request) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>
            <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :organisation_id, collection: @all_organisations << ['other', nil] %>
                </div>

        <div class="form-inputs">
          <%= f.input :name %>
        </div>

                <div class="form-actions">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "Create", :class => 'formsubmit' %>
                </div>
          <% end %>
```

**NEW ATTEMPT:**

I have a create action in my organisation controller, I added this service class request for an email:

```
def create
    @organisation_request = OrganisationRequest.new(organisation_request_params)
    @organisation_request.profile_id = current_user.profile.id

    if @organisation_request.save
      NewOrgRequestService.send_unknown_organisation_requested_flag(organisation_request)
      return redirect_to(profile_path(current_user.profile),
        flash[:alert] => 'Your request is being processed.')
    else
      # Failure scenario below
      @all_organisations    = Organisation.select(:title, :id).map { |org| [org.title, org.id] }

      render :new
    end
  end
```

I then have a services/organisations requests/NewOrgRequestService.rb

```
class OrganisationRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  class NewOrgRequestService
    attr_accessor :organisation_request

    def self.send_unknown_organisation_requested_flag(organisation_request)
        if @organisation_request.name.present?
            AdminNote.unknown_organisation_requested(organisation_request, user_full_name, name).deliver_later
        end 
      end
  end
end
```

The AdminNote mailer has:

```
class AdminNote < ApplicationMailer
    layout 'transactional_mailer'

    def unknown_organisation_requested(organisation_request, user_full_name, name)

        @organisation_request = @organisation_request
        @user_full_name = @organisation_request.user_full_name
        @name = organisation_request.name

    # @greeting = "Hi"
    mail 
    to: "test@testerongmail.com",from: "test@testerongmail.com", subject: "A new organisation"

  end
end
```

This doesnt work, but I'm wondering if Im on the right track? Im not sure if the create action in the controller needs to have some kind of reference to the services/organisation_requests/ path that gets to the file??

I think I may have made a bigger mess than I started with - but I'm out of ideas for things to try next.

Comment: why do you need to use delegate ...i can be done without a delegate module

Comment: i use the delegation for several access points. its useful to me

Answer (score 1):

**This may help you**.

In your mailer method

```
def unknown_organisation(org,user)
   @org = org
   @user = user

   mail(to: "test@testerongmail.com",from: "test@testerongmail.com", subject: "A new organisation")
end
```

In your controller method after saving organization_request and this is how you set your variable. You can pass variable you want.

```
AdminNote.unknown_organization(@organization_request, current_user).deliver_now
```

In your mailer template access passed value as you do in action view. And this is how you use your variable.

```
<%= @org.name %>
<%= @org.full_name %>
```

**Hope this helps**

If you want to queue message or send later you can use ActiveJob to send mails in the background.

For more, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Comment: @Pradeep_Sapkota - thanks for the suggestion. Wouldn't your suggestion send the email to the current user? I don't want to do that. I want to get the :user_full_name delegated to the organisation_reuqest model and find the :name of the attribute submitted with the organisation request. I want to submit those attributes into an email which is sent to a hard coded specified address (which will be internal)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to set the 3 variables in my post. Based on what is submitted with the user's organisation request form. I want to use those variables in an email that is sent to an internal colleague

Comment: @Mel make your question more clear. A user must login to create organization. When organization is saved you save the logged in user to organization_requests table. Assumed that and answered. if you need user related to organization name and he is diffenrent from my explanation use simply '@org.user_full_name' instead.

Comment: @Pradeep_Sapkota - thank you for trying to help me. I'm afraid I don't understand what you're saying. This form is for a user to request permission to join an organisation. The table has an attribute called "name" in it (the name of the organisation they want to join). I want to take that name as well as the user_full_name (a method delegated to the model) and the organisation_request itself and user the content of those variables in an email sent to an internal colleague, after the organisation request is created. Do you know how to set those variables in the mailer method?

Comment: For example, do you mean that I could set a variable in the mailer method as: *user_full_name = *organisation_request.user_full_name and then in the view I can write: <%= user_full_name %>?? Is that your suggestion?  I used * instead of @ because I cant use that symbol more than once in a comment.

Comment: Lots of things to be clear in your question. Please update your question with form and the def you use to create  and save data. and model too

Comment: I added the form I use for users to create a new organisation request.

Comment: I'm not sure that I've understood your suggestion for how I can set variables in the AdminNote mailer method by reference to submitted attributes from this form.

Comment: Hey, @Mel please in your organization_request model there is no def called user_full_name

Comment: Hi @Pradeep - it is delegated to organisation_request - as shown in my post above.

Comment: I think your question is how to set variables in mailer method and problem should has been solved. I have shown you in mailer method there how to pass them and make instance variable. You can use them in template as you do in view.

Comment: I'm sorry - I just have not understood what you have suggested. I don't think I have understood any of your thought process. Thank you for taking the time to try to help.

Comment: I'm sorry Pradeep. I appreciate that you are trying to help me - but none of this makes any sense to me. I can't understand your suggestion or how you think I could go about setting variables to be used in a mailer. Thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: Ok. May be understandings were wrong or I didn't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am super late but here I go.

I understand that you are trying to send in some parameters (values) to mailer so that you can use it while sending an email.

To do so you just need to define a mailer method that accepts some parameters. What you have done is right in your AdminNote Mailer unknown_organization method.

Let's get to your **NEW ATTEMPT**.
Everything you have done there seems about right except you are passing an undefined variable `organization_request`. You have created an instance variable `@organization_request` but you are passing something that is not defined. Here

```
NewOrgRequestService.send_unknown_organisation_requested_flag(organisation_request)
```

That is your first problem. This can be improved as:
Your Organizations#create

```
def create
    @organisation_request = OrganisationRequest.new(organisation_request_params)
    @organisation_request.profile_id = current_user.profile.id

    if @organisation_request.save
      @organisation_request.send_unknown_organisation_requested_flag
      redirect_to(profile_path(current_user.profile),
        flash[:alert] => 'Your request is being processed.')
    else
      # Failure scenario below
      @all_organisations = Organisation.select(:title, :id).map { |org| [org.title, org.id] }

      render :new
    end
  end
```

And your model can be as follows:

```
class OrganisationRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
    def send_unknown_organisation_requested_flag
        if self.name.present?
            AdminNote.unknown_organisation_requested(self).deliver_later
        end 
      end
end
```

*I don't know why you are defining a class inside your model class.*

Your Mailer should look like below:

```
class AdminNote < ApplicationMailer
    layout 'transactional_mailer'

    def unknown_organisation_requested(organisation_request)

        @organisation_request = organisation_request
        @user_full_name = @organisation_request.user_full_name
        @name = organisation_request.name

    # @greeting = "Hi"
    mail 
    to: "test@testerongmail.com",from: "test@testerongmail.com", subject: "A new organisation"

  end
end
```

There are a lot of typos and method implementation errors here.